# Transparent background NSWindow was not recovered

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa, transparent, nswindow

I have a custom NSWindow (BorderlessWindow.swift) and NSView (TransparentView.swift) and I add a label (NSTextField) to TransparentView.

When I hide the label, the TransparentView is not recovered:

Before Hide capture image:

[image]

After Hide capture image:

[image]

How can I fix it?

*BorderlessWindow.swift*

```
class BorderlessWindow: NSWindow {

override init(contentRect: NSRect, styleMask aStyle: Int, backing bufferingType: NSBackingStoreType, `defer` flag: Bool) {

    super.init(contentRect: contentRect,
        styleMask: NSBorderlessWindowMask,
        backing: NSBackingStoreType.Buffered,
        `defer`: false)

    self.alphaValue = 1.0
    self.opaque = false
    self.movableByWindowBackground = true

}

@IBOutlet weak var testString: NSTextField!

@IBAction func clicked(sender: NSButton) {
    if testString.hidden == false {
        testString.hidden = true
    }
    else {
        testString.hidden = false
    }
}

override var canBecomeKeyWindow:Bool {
    get {
        return true
    }
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
}
```

*TransparentView.swift*

```
class TransparentView: NSView {

override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {

    super.drawRect(dirtyRect)

    NSColor.clearColor().set()
    NSRectFill(self.bounds)

    let path = NSBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, xRadius: 10, yRadius: 10)
    let path2 = NSBezierPath(roundedRect: NSMakeRect(self.bounds.origin.x + 10, self.bounds.origin.y + 10, self.bounds.size.width - 20, self.bounds.size.height - 20), xRadius: 10, yRadius: 10)

    NSColor(calibratedRed: 1, green: 0.7, blue: 0, alpha: 0.5).setFill()
    NSColor(calibratedRed: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1).setStroke()

    path2.lineWidth = 3.0
    path.lineJoinStyle = NSLineJoinStyle.RoundLineJoinStyle
    path.lineCapStyle = NSLineCapStyle.RoundLineCapStyle


    path2.fill()
    path2.stroke()

    // Drawing code here.
}



override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
    super.init(frame: frameRect)
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
}

}
```

I found:
When the textField's initial value of hidden property is true(textfield is initialized with hidden state), it works fine.

Comment: Is the text field configured to draw its background (which might be a clear color)? If so, does it behave any better if you turn that off? Also, your `drawRect()` should work in terms of either `dirtyRect` or `self.bounds`, not `self.frame`.

Comment: the text field is configured to do not draw its background. and I still have a same problem. thanks for the reply.

Comment: You're still using `self.frame` for the first path. Have you tried calling `self.invalidateShadow()` after toggling the `hidden` state of the text field?

Comment: self.invalidateShadow() works perfect!!!! thanks @KenThomases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a window with transparent parts, you need to invalidate the shadow after you change what has been drawn. The shadow is computed from the opaque (or mostly-opaque) parts and therefore depends on exactly what gets drawn.

So, after you change the way it draws, whether that has to do with hiding views or redrawing them, you need to call `invalidateShadow()` on the window.

Comment: Note: I had to do `self.window!.hasShadow = false` to get it to invalidate